# I tried everything aws s3 cp still gives access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have tried giving myself AmazonS3FullAccess, wrote a stupid policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and while `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name/someprefix` works, `aws s3 cp` gives access denied, and `aws --region us-west-2 s3api get-object-acl --bucket bucket-name --key "i-copy-pasted-this-from-list-objects"` also gives access denied and so does `get-object`. I compared  `aws sts get-caller-identity` to the IAM UI ARN and it is the same. This question came up a few times but none of the answers are helpful and more importantly, they don't indicate how would I go about debugging the problem?

Comment: Does the bucket itself have a bucket policy? It could potentially include deny clauses that override your permissions. I'm assuming that you have indeed verified that you're making these API requests with the correct credentials. BTW the policy shown has an error - both of the specified actions are object-level actions so they are not relevant to the bucket resource `"arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"`.

Comment: Also, you didn't say, but I'm assuming this bucket is in the same AWS account as the IAM user you're using. And that your `aws s3 cp` commands are trying to download an object to your local disk, as opposed to copying an object to another S3 bucket (that you do not have permission for).

Comment: The policy you show does not grant permission to list the contents of the bucket, but you say that `aws s3 ls` works for the bucket. Therefore, you are receiving permissions through some other method (such as `AmazonS3FullAccess`). Are you able to copy an object _to_ the bucket (`aws s3 cp localfile.txt s3://bucket-name/`)? If that works, can you download it (`aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/localfile.txt .`)?